# What is the name of the pedal assembly in an aircraft cockpit?

Tags: flight-controls, terminology, rudder

I'm proofreading a document about rudder control systems and client insists on calling the pedal assembly under the pilot's feet the "rudder". Would this ever be used?

Comment: 757toga’s answer explains it well, but an example sentence might yield better feedback about whether the term is being used in the correct context.

Answer (score 24):

In an airplane the pedal assembly under the pilot's feet is called the **"rudder pedals"** (not "the rudder").

In some situations (e.g., when giving instruction), and referring to one of the two rudder pedals, the instructor may tell the student *"you need to add just a bit more left/right '**rudder**' to stay coordinated"* (while banking the airplane).

It would also not be unusual for an instructor, as in the example above, to tell the the student *"you need to add just a bit more left/right '**pedal**' to stay coordinated."*

Comment: People like to be metaphorical. It's entirely conceivable for an instructor to point at the pedals and call them the "rudder". Same as pointing at the altimeter and saying "altitude" or the cockpit and saying "my office". However, such instructors risk the student not getting the metaphor. At best this is informal. Depending on context, a dangerous habit.

Comment: correct, and saying "add more rudder" is correct, using the rudder pedals to do so is implied (but for minute adjustments, rudder trim for example could work as well).

Answer (score 14):

Proper term for the collection of parts that includes the pedals, the struts they are mounted on, and any bearings etc, up to the push rod(s) that drive the rudder control circuit, is "Rudder Pedal Assembly".

If you were describing it in a technical document that describes the control system, that's the term you would use.

If you were describing it just for the pilot's benefit, so he/she knows where to put their feet, you would just say "Rudder Pedals".

Never "Rudder", that being the swingy bit at the back.

Answer (score 3):

It would very common for an instructor to say "give it some more right rudder", but "step on the right rudder" would be unusual, and "put your feet on the rudder/s" would never be used.  The phrase used in the latter two examples would almost always be "rudder *pedals/s*".  Certainly a mechanic or designer would never refer to the pedal assembly as the "rudder".  The answer to your question is "no".